# Evaluation expressions in frame only yields UNBOUND-VARIABLE

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, slime

I'm using SLIME to debug my Common Lisp function. Inside the function, I've made it artificially signal an error (trying to "debug"—perhaps I should be stepping) like so:

```
(define-condition unknown-zone (error)
  ((text :initarg :text :reader text)))

(defun parse-mime-date (date)
  (let ((last-space (position #\Space date :from-end t)))
    (let ((date-time (net.telent.date:parse-time (subseq date 0 last-space)))
          (zone (subseq date (1+ last-space))))
      (unless (or (char= (elt zone 0) #\+)
                  (char= (elt zone 0) #\-))
        (error 'unknown-zone :text (format nil "Unknown timezone: ~a" zone)))
      (let ((hours (parse-integer (subseq zone 0 3)))
            (minutes (parse-integer
                      (concatenate 'string
                                   (list (elt zone 0))
                                   (subseq zone 3)))))
        (error 'unknown-zone :text "LOL")
        (let ((adjusted-date-time (- date-time (* 60 (+ minutes (* 60 hours))))))
          (format t "date-time: ~a; zone: ~a~%" date-time zone)
          (format t "adjusted: ~a" (net.telent.date:universal-time-to-http-date adjusted-date-time)))))))
```

I'm trying to work around what appears to be a deficiency in `net.telent.date:parse-time` (it seems to botch up timezone handling, though I'm not 100% yet).

The "LOL" `unknown-zone` error is of course the artificial breakpoint.

When it hits this part of the function, SLDB faithfully opens up with the backtrace:

```
Bad type argument:
  NS-MAIL2ZD::UNKNOWN-ZONE
   [Condition of type SIMPLE-TYPE-ERROR]

Restarts:
 0: [RETRY] Retry SLIME REPL evaluation request.
 1: [*ABORT] Return to SLIME's top level.
 2: [REMOVE-FD-HANDLER] Remove #<SB-IMPL::HANDLER INPUT on descriptor 7: #<CLOSURE (LABELS SWANK-BACKEND::RUN :IN SWANK-BACKEND:ADD-FD-HANDLER) {10030AD9FB}>>
 3: [ABORT] Exit debugger, returning to top level.

Backtrace:
  0: (MAKE-CONDITION NS-MAIL2ZD::UNKNOWN-ZONE :TEXT "LOL")
  1: (ERROR NS-MAIL2ZD::UNKNOWN-ZONE :TEXT "LOL")
  2: (NS-MAIL2ZD:PARSE-MIME-DATE "Wed, 14 Mar 2012 06:59:36 +1100")
  3: (SB-INT:SIMPLE-EVAL-IN-LEXENV (NS-MAIL2ZD:PARSE-MIME-DATE *LOL*) #<NULL-LEXENV>)
  4: (EVAL (NS-MAIL2ZD:PARSE-MIME-DATE *LOL*))
 --more--
```

Then I page down to the frame:

```
Backtrace:
  0: (MAKE-CONDITION NS-MAIL2ZD::UNKNOWN-ZONE :TEXT "LOL")
  1: (ERROR NS-MAIL2ZD::UNKNOWN-ZONE :TEXT "LOL")
      Locals:
        SB-KERNEL::ARGUMENTS = (:TEXT "LOL")
        SB-KERNEL::DATUM = NS-MAIL2ZD::UNKNOWN-ZONE
  2: (NS-MAIL2ZD:PARSE-MIME-DATE "Wed, 14 Mar 2012 06:59:36 +1100")
```

Now I hit <kbd>e</kbd> to invoke `sldb-eval-in-frame` and type `last-space`, as that should be available where the error was signaled.

It seems this isn't how it's meant (?) to work:

```
The variable LAST-SPACE is unbound.
   [Condition of type UNBOUND-VARIABLE]

Restarts:
 0: [ABORT] Return to sldb level 1.
 1: [RETRY] Retry SLIME REPL evaluation request.
 2: [*ABORT] Return to SLIME's top level.
 3: [REMOVE-FD-HANDLER] Remove #<SB-IMPL::HANDLER INPUT on descriptor 7: #<CLOSURE (LABELS SWANK-BACKEND::RUN :IN SWANK-BACKEND:ADD-FD-HANDLER) {10030AD9FB}>>
 4: [ABORT] Exit debugger, returning to top level.

Backtrace:
  0: ((LAMBDA (#:G1144)) #<unavailable argument>)
 --more--
```

Is there a way to do what I want? Am I over-complicating matters?

Thanks!

---

**Addendum:** I've tried using `(break)` (this seems a tad more canonical), but I still can't see `let`-bound variables with <kbd>e</kbd>. :<

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the complete name of the symbol (i.e. `package::symbol-name`) instead of just the symbol name (i.e. `symbol-name`). In the current case, maybe `net.telent.date::last-space`.

Also make sure that you compiled with debugging support set to maximum (for instance, try placing a `(declaim (optimize debug))` before your function and recompile the file  - <kbd>C-c C-k</kbd>).

Checking that the code you're trying to debug has enough debug information: in the sldb window, put the cursor on the relevant line in the backtrace and press <kbd>t</kbd> - this should expand the frame and show values for all the locals. Pressing <kbd>t</kbd> again collapses the local frame information. If there is not enough debug information, you won't see the local variables, but some made up names (such as `SB-DEBUG:ARG-0` under SBCL). Inside the sldb window, if you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> with the cursor on a value, it will expand that value into an inspector window (useful if the value is a long list which is shown truncated).

Also, SLIME debugging support seems to vary with the implementation. The advice above works on SBCL under Linux, YMMV under different implementations.

Comment: An alternative to using the `package::symbol-name` when trying to evaluate things in the debugger is to select the relevant package in the REPL using `in-package`.

Comment: Thank you! `(declaim (optimize debug))` was the incantation I was missing. After that, all the locals at that point are listed in the "t" listing (and accessible via "e"). I've also just learned about the `package::not-necessarily-exported-symbol` syntax—thanks!

Comment: You can also use `C-u` `C-c` `C-k` to compile with maximum debug settings.

Comment: @Daimrod Didn't know about that, hope I'll remember it!

Comment: @ArlenCuss: You can also use a positive argument to compile with maximum speed settings (e.g. `M-1` `C-c` `C-k`).

Answer (score 4):

There is another option to debug a Lisp function: use an *interpreter* if available. Most implementations can switch between interpreted and compiled code. You could run all code compiled, but the function you want to debug could be running interpreted. In the extreme case you could even break into a stepper for the interpreted function (if available).

Note that it makes sense to define a default optimization setting based on your requirements.

- don't set **safety** very low globally. Do that only in code sections where this is useful.
- don't set **speed** very high globally. Do that only in code sections where this is useful.
- keep debug information, use a setting of 2. Depending on the implementation a high debug setting may shut down tail call optimization (TCO) - which can be undesirable for execution and desirable for debugging.

I would propose different settings for:

- development: safe + debug friendly
- deployment: safe
- optimization of numeric code, locally for speed

By default you should use a setting that is useful for interactive use:

- speed 1-2. speed is somewhat important
- safety 2-3. safety is very important. all operations are checked at runtime
- debug 2-3. debug information is kept and the operations should be interruptible by a debugger.
- space 1. The size of the code is not important.
- compilation-speed 1. The speed of the compilation process is not so important.

The range is from 0 to 3. No number defaults to 3. 3 is higher.

Depending on the implementation there might be additional optimization settings and also some variables to configure the compiler.

In speed-critical sections you can set speed higher than safety and debug. But be aware that in some cases this changes the semantics of the code execution (error detection, overflows, ...) and that missing runtime checks may make it possible that your code corrupts the Lisp heap.

In some delivery situations it also may be useful to to have a very low debug setting. But if your Lisp compiler is set to high speed optimizations and low debug, debugging the code by looking at the backtrace of the stack may get much harder.

Answer (score 3):

The variable seems to be optimized away. From the [SBCL Manual](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/sbcl.pdf):

> The value of a variable may be unavailable for these reasons:
>
> 1. The value of the debug optimization quality may have omitted debug
>      information needed to determine whether the variable is available.
>      Unless a variable is an argument, its value will only be available
>      when debug is at least
> 2. The compiler did lifetime analysis and
>      determined that the value was no longer needed, even though its scope
>      had not been exited. Lifetime analysis is inhibited when the debug
>      optimization quality is
> 3. The variable’s name is an uninterned
>      symbol (gensym). To save space, the compiler only dumps debug
>      information about uninterned variables when the debug optimization
>      quality is
> 4. The frame’s location is unknown (see Section 5.3.5 [Unknown Locations and Interrupts], page 31) because the debugger was entered
>      due to an interrupt or unexpected hardware error. Under these
>      conditions the values of arguments will be available, but might be
>      incorrect. This is the exception mentioned above.
> 5. The variable (or
>      the code referencing it) was optimized out of existence. Variables
>      with no reads are always optimized away. The degree to which the
>      compiler deletes variables will depend on the value of the
>      compilation-speed optimization quality, but most source-level
>      optimizations are done under all compilation policies.
> 6. The variable is never set and its definition looks like `(LET ((var1 var2)) ...)` In this case, `var1` is substituted with `var2`.
> 7. The variable is never set  and is referenced exactly once. In this case, the reference is substituted with the variable initial value

You can see all available local variables with <kbd>t</kbd>.

If you add a reference to your variable *after* your error conditions, probably you'll be able to get its value in the corresponding debug frame.

Comment: Thanks for the reference! In this case it was indeed the first of those points causing my issue, the solution being to `(declaim (optimize debug))` or the like.